# 'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenize'

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

It is first time to play with python, I am trying to copy and run some codes available online to understand how they work, but some of them are not working. This is an example of a problem that I faced when I try to copy a program that does the part of speech in python using NLTK.

```
import nltk
import re
import time

exampleArray = ['The incredibly intimidating NLP scares people who are sissies.']

def processLanguage():
    try:
        for item in exampleArray:
        tokenized = nltk.word_tokenized(item)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)


processLanguage()
```

The problem is when I run this code, I have this message:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenize'
'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenized'
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Works fine when I correct `word_tokenized` to `word_tokenize`. Voting to close.

Comment: Are you really saying you had one message mentioning `word_tokenize` and one mentioning `word_tokenized`?  If it was `word_tokenized`, then I'd say it was a typo; if it was `word_tokenize`, I'd say you'd probably shadowed `nltk` with a module of your own called `nltk.py`; but I can't explain why you'd see both.

Comment: Nothing changed when I changed it to word_tokenize. And I have seen a youtube video running exact code and it worked with him properly.

Comment: What have you called your program ? If you have called it 'nltk.py' (or you have another file in the same folder/directory called 'nltk.py') then your code wont work, as python will load your file, rather than the library. You must ensure that you don't have any files with the same names as an of your libraries that you are using.

Comment: I called it simple.py and I used to have nltk.py and nltk.pyc when I delete them now it is better as it gives me 'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenized' (just once) not twice as in the actual question. Do you think that there is another file should be omitted?

Comment: Now this is gone, as the program asked me to do nltk.download() I downloaded it and after that when I run it again, it did not give me any answer. Is it loading?

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Write this in your code, perhaps 'punkt' is missing. After downloading you can erase it.